# Force Contacts update in iOS9

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, contacts

Sometimes I update a contact on Mac and I need it immediately on my iPhone. Until iOS 8.x, to force contacts to update, was necessary to go in contacts, go back to groups then scroll tu update...easy!
Now, iOS9, scroll to update in groups disappeared and I can't find an alternative way to force contacts update!

The easiest way I find to do that is to create an imaginary contact then remove it and this way works but it doesn't sound a lot as official!

Has someone has find alternative methods?

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on what service is providing the contacts? Also, you might tell us how you have each contact sync set up. Are you using fetch or push? Basically what works for iCloud might have different effects for google or exchange.

Comment: I didn't change anything, simply updating to iOS 9 the "pull to refresh" in contacts app disappeared!

Answer (score 1):

In Settings, visit "Mail, Contacts Calendars." Scroll down and select "Fetch New Data." Then, on that screen, temporarily turn on "Push," and then make sure iCloud is also set to push, so that new data is pushed from the server automatically whenever possible. This should push through any new data immediately.

You may then want to switch Push off for data, and choose one of the Fetch settings to save battery.

Comment: Uh, why did this get a down-vote? I had this problem, I found this question, I tried this, and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you sync you contacts with your google account, then simply check your email.
IOS syncs mail and contacts at the same time.

Comment: It doesn't work